# CURL - Just showing login form

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a site to grab some data but am just being presented with the login form each time and the cookie file remains empty.

I am using the following code:

```
<?php

$cookie_file = 'cookie.txt';

if (! file_exists($cookie_file) || ! is_writable($cookie_file)){
    echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
    exit;
}//cookie_file is writable, so this is not the issue

$login_url = 'https://portal.processing.com';

//These are the post data username and password
$post_data = 'username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD';

//Create a curl object
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie_file));

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://portal.processing.com/query.transaction-view.php?id=9452931');

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

echo $postResult;

?>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct form path - try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code of the login form, it contains:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
```

Add those to your POST values, and see if that produces the desired result.

Edit:

I took another look, and the form posts via jQuery to https://portal.processing.com/forms/login_check.php. Try posting to that page instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove realpath() from CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR & CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
2. use urlencode while creating array of parameters as,

   $fields = array('username' => urlencode ($uname),
               'password' => urlencode ($passwd),
              );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
      $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
     }
3. trim your $fields_string as,

   trim($fields_string);

http://www.technologyworkshops.net/php/php-curl-not-working-with-cookies-t153.html

Comment: Done all these and included the hidden fields from the answer below. Still doing the same of just showing a login form.